# Helmet headshot protection for face shot?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

A level 1 or 2 Helmet visually does not protect the players face.

Does it always give Protection for headshots, no matter if hit in the face or somewhere else on the head where the Helmet does not cover it?
Or only for the space where the helmet really covers the head?

Bonus question, does the neck also counts to headshots? (it is also visually not covered by helmets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Helmet's will protect you from shots to the face.**

In fact all helmets have the exact same hitbox, so there is no difference between hitting a player with a motorcycle helmet or a level 3 helmet.

This Video goes into depth about the mechanics of Armour:

Even though the video is from April, there isn't evidence that they have changed the mechanic in the recent patches.

---

Regarding hit boxes and whether the neck counts as a headshot, No it does not. The neck is neither protected by wearing a Helmet or a vest. You can see an indepth look into the player hitboxes in the video below. (Pardon the commentary, but the data seems good):

Comment: @kl78 not off the top of my head but let me see what I can find